# Installing and Using System.Data.SQLite (An ADO.NET provider)

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, system.data.sqlite

I am a newbie in regards to System.Data.SQLite and .NET, so bear with me. I can't seem to get System.Data.SQLite even installed correctly. The self-installer completed and everything seemed to be kosher, but nothing seems to be working. In VC# Express, I tried to create a little sample program(http://pastebin.com/m8f7cec), but it's saying that it can't find System.Data.SQLite at the line: using System.Data.SQLite;. Also the Database explorer always errors out when I try to make a new connection, starting with, "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data"... I also don't know what to put in the Connection string. Can someone help just get this started? I am familiar with SQLite itself.
Thanks,
deftonix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the installer does is put the proper libraries on your local machine, as well as enable the plug-ins within Visual Studio to allow you to explore your databases via Server Explorer.

You still need to Right Click on your "References" section in your project and add a reference to the library in order for it to work at runtime.

Comment: Well, I feel dumb, that worked perfectly for accessing the DB through code. However, the VC# database explorer still doesn't work correctly. I am getting the same cryptic error message no matter what Connection String I use.

Comment: Are you setting the connection string in your app.config file? The location often changes between development and runtime, and the best bet is to update the connection string there. I saw your screenshot, but it looks to be occurring when creating a new data connection. Do you get the same error when running the app?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a reference within your project to the System.Data.SQLite dll.

For the connection string, try http://www.connectionstrings.com, it has the format for most common connections.

Comment: Isn't the reference
  using System.Data.SQLite;
?  
Or am I missing something?  
Thanks.

Comment: See Dillie-O's comment, you need to actually add a reference to the dll within the project. There should be a references folder, right click on that, select 'Add references..' then navigate to where the auto-extractor put the dll (or better yet set up a lib folder within your project and copy the dll there). 'Using' only specifies that that particular class can use the dll, not the project in general.

Comment: Yes, that worked, however, the VC# database explorer still doesn't work correctly. I am getting the same cryptic error message no matter what Connection String I use. See here -> http://tinypic.com/r/rcsl5g/6

Answer (score 0):

This is now available through NuGet (the question was asked 8 years ago when I'm guessing it was not in NuGet).

Add it with NuGet and that will download the DLL(s) and add it as a reference.